# Full-screen intent not opening with notification

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

I’m trying to show a full-screen intent with my notification (running on a android 13 device). The notification is sent, but the intent isn’t opening.

I’ve granted the required permissions and my manifest content is as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />

<activity
    android:name=".RingActivity"
    android:exported="false"
    android:showOnLockScreen="true"
    android:turnScreenOn="true" />
<receiver android:name=".infrastructure.Receiver" />
```

Here’s the relevant code for creating the notification and full-screen intent:

```
private fun createChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val channel = NotificationChannel("my_channel_id", "Alarm", importance)
        val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}

private fun notify(alarm:Alarm, intent:Intent){
    createChannel()
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "my_channel_id")
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float)
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .setContentText("description")
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
        .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent,true)
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) return
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(alarm.id,builder.build())
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out why the full-screen intent isn’t opening?

*this is the intent im trying to call :

```
val intent = Intent(context,RingActivity::class.java).also {
        it.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        it.putExtra("id",alarm.id)
}
```

Comment: What is the Intent you're passing to notify()?

Comment: @MikhailGuliaev hi there , here is my intent :
Intent(context,RingActivity::class.java).also {
            it.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            it.putExtra("id",alarm.id)
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for your help! I managed to fix the issue. It turned out that the problem only occurred when I scheduled the notification with a short delay. It works fine with longer delays now